# Is there in Cypher sometihg like RETURN all?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb

I have a code

```
MATCH (n1)-[r:CREATED_ON {manufactureDate: '11-03-2021'}]->(n2)
RETURN n1, r, n2;
```

Is there a shorthand to replace `RETURN n1, r, n2;` that would be equivalent to saying, "Return me all values of all nodes and relationships"? Like `RETURN *`.

Comment: It is recommended when asking a question to include everything you have tried so far. Did you try `RETURN *` and did you get an error? `RETURN *` is supported in most Cypher and openCypher implementations and does exactly what you describe.

Comment: I see you used the `memgraphdb` tag. Checking that documentation it says that `RETURN *` is supported.  https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/clauses/return#1-returning-nodes

Comment: Thank you @KelvinLawrence! I've tried it again, and now it works. I had the stupidest typo ever: I've critter `RERUN *` instead `RETURN *` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kelvin Lawrence has said in comments, `RETURN *` exists, and it works. I just had a typo in my command.